# Whats' wrong with this script?

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/Ld5s4jLw/1/

I can't figure what is wrong with this, it doesn't work, I tried many things but can't make it work...

```js
function toggleAutre(bloc) {
  if ($('#' + bloc + '_oui').is(':checked')) {
    $('#' + bloc + '_texte').show('slow');
    alert('Oui');
  } else if ($('#' + bloc + '_non').is(':checked')) {
    $('#' + bloc + '_texte').hide('slow');
    alert('Non');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="nbre_poste_inoccupe" id="nbre_poste_inoccupe_oui" value="1" onclick="toggleAutre('nbre_poste_inoccupe');" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="nbre_poste_inoccupe_oui">OUI</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="nbre_poste_inoccupe_text_div" style="display: none;">
    <label for="nbre_poste_inoccupe_text" style="font-size: 0.7em; font-weight: 400;">Si OUI, combien ?</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="nbre_poste_inoccupe" id="nbre_poste_inoccupe_text" style="width: 5em;" value="1" onclick="toggleAutre('nbre_poste_inoccupe');" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="nbre_poste_inoccupe" id="nbre_poste_inoccupe_non" value="0">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="nbre_poste_inoccupe_non">NON</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What's it supposed to do? What does it do? What's in the js console? Etc.

Comment: Also please check errors in console. Your fiddle demo won't work (and throws errors) because the function is not in global window namespace due to the way fiddle automatically wraps code in `onload` callback

Comment: Is there a reason that you're reaching your elements with jquery but on the other side you define and try to run your function with plain javascript? That's kinda pointless

Comment: Debugged [https://jsfiddle.net/Ld5s4jLw/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld5s4jLw/7/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the dynamic `id` that you want to display it not correct. You are using the selector (after calculation, right?) `#nbre_poste_inoccupe_texte` to find the div `nbre_poste_inoccupe_text_div`. Just fix it and it will work for you.

```js
function toggleAutre(bloc) {
  if ($('#' + bloc + '_oui').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('#' + bloc + '_texte_div');
    $('#' + bloc + '_text_div').show('slow');
    alert('Oui');
  } else if ($('#' + bloc + '_non').is(':checked')) {
    $('#' + bloc + '_texte').hide('slow');
    alert('Non');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="nbre_poste_inoccupe" id="nbre_poste_inoccupe_oui" value="1" onclick="toggleAutre('nbre_poste_inoccupe');" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="nbre_poste_inoccupe_oui">OUI</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="nbre_poste_inoccupe_text_div" style="display: none;">
    <label for="nbre_poste_inoccupe_text" style="font-size: 0.7em; font-weight: 400;">Si OUI, combien ?</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="nbre_poste_inoccupe" id="nbre_poste_inoccupe_text" style="width: 5em;" value="1" onclick="toggleAutre('nbre_poste_inoccupe');" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="nbre_poste_inoccupe" id="nbre_poste_inoccupe_non" value="0">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="nbre_poste_inoccupe_non">NON</label>
  </div>
</div>
```